# Easiest way to automatically pause music when removing device from Dock?

Tags: music-player, dock, motorola-droid-4

I'd like the music on my Droid 4 to automatically pause when I pull the thing out of the dock, no matter what. I don't need it to auto-play again later, just go to pause and stay there.

What's the easiest way to do this? I'm willing to buy an app if it makes this simple.

I normally use the built-in music player, but again I'm willing to try something else if it would help.

If it's relevant, I have the phone set to not go into the dock app for desktop use.

Comment: AFAIK *Tasker* also offers media control. I've not tested that context, but would expect it to work like "Condition: Docked → Task: Variable Set: %DOCKED=1; Exit-Task: Pause" (the "Task" can be some other dummy, as for your case you only need the exit task, or you could place something useful there). Though being a payed app, there's a free 7day trial on their website. See also our [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info).

Comment: I *have* tested it. You can do exactly this in Tasker using the "Docked" state as the trigger, with an exit task set up to use the "Media Control" action, which provides a "Pause" command.

Comment: @harbichidian Thanks for testing/approving! I've made it an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments already (and which [harbichidian](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/51418/harbichidian) thankfully approved), this can be done using [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker):

- **Condition:** State → Docked
- **Task:** (put something here you want to be done when placing the device in dock, or substitute some dummy like "Variable Set: %DUMMY = 1")
- **Exit Task:** Media Control → Pause

There might be several other approaches to this. I still hold *Tasker* being at least one of the better solutions (if not even the best) is you can do so much more with it. Just check the questions tagged "tasker", or follow the links in our [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) to get an idea.

Comment: As a note: For the DROID4, it's necessary to turn off the 'simulate media buttons' checkbox when creating the pause task. I assume that's because the DROID4 doesn't have any buttons to simulate.